# how to remove WordPress tag on post

Tags: php, json, wordpress

hi i want to make rest api to get the post from wordpress database . as the code below here

```
$query="select wp_postmeta.meta_value,wp_terms.*,wp_posts.* from wp_posts
left join wp_term_relationships ON wp_posts.id=wp_term_relationships.object_id
left join wp_term_taxonomy on  wp_term_taxonomy.term_id=wp_term_relationships.object_id
left join wp_terms on wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id
left join wp_postmeta on wp_postmeta.post_id=wp_posts.id
where 1=1 order by post_date desc
limit 40";
        $query_run=  mysql_query($query);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {

            $query_image=  mysql_query("select meta_value from wp_postmeta where meta_key='_wp_attached_file' and post_id='".$row['id']."'");
            $row1=  mysql_fetch_assoc($query_image);
          $row['image']=$row1['meta_value']; 
          $detail[]=$row;
        }

echo json_encode($detail);
```

The problem is that i got lot of html tag. i use stri_tags() function and preg_replace().
but i does not got any responsive json. is there any solution for that or any other api that is in build  for this task plz help me

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: why you not used rss feed for that?

Comment: i need to make api not rss feed

Comment: show us where you try replace.